# Facebook comments loop very very slow

Tags: php, facebook, json

I have this function in order to retrieve the count of Facebook comments to blog posts:

```
function comment_count($url) { 

 $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url));
 return ($json->$url->comments) ? $json->$url->comments : 0;
}
```

However if I insert it in a loop fetching the results of a query in order to retrieve five posts on a page, this function is seriously affecting the speed of the website (the page takes up to 6-7 seconds to load).

Is there a way to avoid this? Why is it so slow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a comma separated list of URLs to the ids parameter to get all the counts at once, or alternatively, cache them on the server side and use those values.

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.google.com,http://www.bing.com,http://www.yahoo.com

This is specified in Facebook's [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) under the section "selection"

An example implementation follows:

```
<?php
function comment_count($urls) {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . implode(',', array_map("rawurlencode", $urls))));
    $output = Array();
    foreach($json as $url=>$data)
    {
        $output[$url] = isset($data->comments) ? $data->comments : 0;
    }
    return $output;
}
var_dump(comment_count(Array('http://www.facebook.com/', 'http://www.google.com')));
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much echeese! That was a very efficient and elegant solution!!! Very recommended to everyone facing with my problem :-)